# Running a store through Tor - what are the setup options available?

Tags: bitcoind, e-wallet, tor, hosting, website-integration

I am required to setup a store that will operate through Tor and accept Bitcoin payments only. I know I can run the standard client on the server and make it connect to peers only through Tor. However, are there any other options available for handling Bitcoin side of things - hosting the wallet, creating accounts, receiving money and so forth? Do any eWallets or other services allow access through Tor?

Comment: I'm curious what's great about a tor-based e-commerce site. If there's shipping, you'll need the buyer's address. If there's digital download, you'll need to give them a link, and it won't matter if they are or aren't TOR. Saving the user's session via cookie / session vars to continue to use their system makes sense.

Comment: The benefit is that it's a lot more difficult for a government to shut down a Tor hidden service than an open web site. See: Silk Road

Comment: If you're doing what Silk Road do you would want to run your own Bitcoin-Qt and not use some third-party online service.

Answer (score 7):

Try using bitwasp. It seems to provide a lot of features you need. Try it and let us know if it works.

https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/BitWasp

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=109223.0

Comment: Very cool! Looks like a codeigniter instance. W

Comment: Does BitWasp seem to work? I am also required to start an anonymous marketplace, but there do not seem to be any reliable choices out there.

Comment: Bit-Wasp abandonware or close been hacked to many time to count sadly.

Comment: Yea please don't use Bitwasp the marketplace :)  it's a project that I could never keep up with maintaining and really isn't secure or high quality code.

Answer (score 1):

[BTCPay Server](https://btcpayserver.org/) "is a self-hosted, open-source cryptocurrency payment processor. It's secure, private, censorship-resistant and free."

There are still some outstanding [issues around Tor](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/labels/Tor) though.